# How to include specific property to changes part Audit.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, audit.net

I have two primary columns and its set by with HasKey (fluent API .net core)
When I tried to update a record from the table all columns have an old and new value in changes. but not the primary key. I need these primary key filed in changes is there any way to include these properties in changes

Comment: Please provide more details like which Audit.NET extensions are you using, and your configuration/setup code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using `Audit.EntityFramework` library. Note the `Changes` property on the [audit event output](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#evententry) will only include the columns that have changed and will not include the primary key.

But the audit event output includes the primary key on the `PrimaryKey` property.

If you need to change the output format, you can use [Custom Actions](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions) or a [Custom Data Provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#data-providers).